# How js function in a web page is executed and how can I mimic the invoke

Tags: javascript

The picture shows a print screen of right-clicked view source page in Chrome browser. With a search in the full context of source, I only found one reference  of method **freshPage**. I didn't found the definition. So I'm puzzled how the script is executed by the browser, since the **freshPage** method seems didn't like a builtin Javascript function. I didn't see any other script  during the page loading. 
How can I mimic the action to get return value of the function?

[image]

I realized I had missed the more.js files responded from the server, with the aid of the comments and replies. I found the definition in the file.

Comment: You can call it from console to get return value. `freshPage(...`

Comment: http://appstore.huawei.com/more/all

Comment: @wason, check [this](http://i.imgur.com/tKEHnt9.png).

Comment: Yes, I didn't find it just now when refreshing

Comment: I'm blocked to ask questions. Anyone know how to unblock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two real possibilities:

1. The `freshPage` function is provided by a script on the page. That may be a `<script src="..."></script>` which refers to a separate resource (seems likely), or an inline `<script>/*code here*/</script>`, or
2. That call will throw a `ReferenceError`.

In this case, it's #1: The page loads `more.js` via this script tag: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.vmall.com/js/all/more.js?version=2.9.5.20150418"></script>` which declares the function.

> How can I mimic the action to get return value of the function?

Just...call it. That can be from a script you inject in the page, a bookmarklet, or the console.

---

It's not the case here, but note that it's entirely possible to remove a script after it's been executed. For instance:

```
<script id="foo">
function doSomething() {
    // ...
}
setTimeout(function() {
    var script = document.getElementById("foo");
    script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
}, 0);
</script>
```

Once the page containing that was loaded, there would be a `doSomething` function defined at global scope, and no `script` tag defining it present on the page anymore. ("View source" should show it, but not the live DOM inspector shown in your screenshot.)

But again, the page you linked doesn't do that. The script tag is perfectly easy to find, in both "view source" and the DOM inspector.

Comment: [Here](http://appstore.huawei.com/js/all/more.js?version=2.9.5.20150418)'s the page with the function `freshPage`'s declaration.

Comment: @user7393973: Yeah, I'd added that.